# Linear Transformations: Scaling along the line $y=x$

Tags: matrices

What is the geometric meaning of scaling an object by a factor $k$ along the line $y=x$?
What will be the shape of a square with vertices $(2,1)$, $(3,2)$, $(3,1)$, and $(2,2)$ if it is scaled by a factor $5$ along the line $y=x$? I really appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 1):

The property of "scaling along $x=y$ by a factor of $5$" does not determine a specific linear transformation. Therefore one cannot say what happens to the square you specify except that the corner $(2,2)$ of the square is mapped to $(10,10)$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to stretch along the line $y=x$ while leaving dimensions perpendicular to the line unchanged.  This would be similar to stretching horizontally by multiplying all $x$ coordinates by $5$ while leaving the $y$ coordinates unchanged.  The easiest way is to rotate axes.  Define a new set of axes by $s=x+y, t=y-x$.  The $s$ axis is the line $y=x$ and the $t$ axis is the line $y=-x$.  We can invert the transformation, finding $x=\frac 12(s-t), y=\frac 12(s+t)$  Then to stretch along $y=x$ by a factor $5$ we change $s$ to $5s$.  Now $x'=\frac 12(5s-t)=\frac 12(6x+4y), y'=\frac 12 (5s+t)=\frac 12(4x+6y)$.  This leaves the origin unchanged, moves $(1,1)$ to $(5,5)$ and leaves $(1,-1)$ unchanged as requested.